# Website not showing on iframe even using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, x-frame-options

I'm using this code to show `http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/` in an `iframe`

```
<iframe src="http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/" width="837" height="544"> 
</iframe>
```

And this code using jquery:

```
$("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/">');
```

But it's not showing anything, I tried other website then it works. Some says that it might probably because of X-Frame-Options being set to that site.

Please help.

Comment: Please post the relevant html and javascript, this information is insufficient.

Comment: Well, does that site set the X-Frame-Options header?

Comment: Without sample code, it will not be easy for others to help you. Please update your question with some samples.

Comment: i'm using http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/ to test my code.

@EdCottrell i really don't know about that if that site set the X-frame-options

Comment: if the X-Frame-Options is being set in that site, does it mean that you cannot iframed that site? ..even using jquery won't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
 $("#siteloader").append($('<iframe width="837" height="544" src="http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/"></iframe'));
```

Comment: i also tried this code in http://jsfiddle.net/SsJsL/ but its not showing..tnks for your help guys..

Answer (score 1):

You're not going to be able to frame this, because the site uses `X-Frame-Options`. I did this request:

```
GET /find-a-location HTTP/1.1
Host: www.solstas.com
```

And got this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 176
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /error/internal-server-error?aspxerrorpath=/find-a-location
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Umbraco-Version: 4.7
Set-Cookie: UserLatitude=29.8301; path=/
Set-Cookie: UserLongitude=-95.4739; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Fri, 14 Mar 2014 06:15:15 GMT

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/error/internal-server-error?aspxerrorpath=/find-a-location">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

The `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN` means this page shouldn't be displayed in a frame, including an iframe. Practically speaking, it means you can't do it, because pretty much all modern browsers will obey this request.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to load `iframe` source to jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#iframe').attr('src', 'http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/');
});
```

**Note : This will work if that domain(www.solstas.com)  permits cross-origin framing**

Comment: I have already added the reason as a note there.Please check any other site that support cross-origin framing to check that code.

Comment: Actually "http://www.solstas.com/find-a-location/" site is showing internal server error, there is nothing wrong with iframe